# firebase 'INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Invalid metadata response'

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Getting this error when calling

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({....})
admin.auth().getUserByEmail('<email address>')
```

The same error happens when calling

```
admin.auth().getUser('<uid>')
```

This only happens for some email addresses. When I use the Authentication dashboard I can look up these users by email but for some reason retrieving them from the api rejects with this error

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. You should file a bug report here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/
and include your project id, some cases where it always works, and some cases where it never works.

Comment: thanks, Jen, I filed a bug with details and examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on firebase-admin version 4.0.4

Found this in the release notes.

[image]